# Pull from multiple endpoints in a Camel route

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route which grabs json from an endpoint, I was wondering how to extend this such that the route grabs from multiple endpoints instead? So imagine there is a `report.2.endpoint`, `report.3.endpoint`, etc..

```java
    from("direct:report").toD("${properties:report.api}/${properties:report.1.endpoint}")
      .split(jsonpath("$.sectionList[0].items[*]"),new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
        .marshal().json()
        .unmarshal(df)
        .convertBodyTo(CannonicalReport.class)
      .end()
      .marshal().json()
      .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("${properties:report.1.output.file}"))
      .toD("file://${properties:report.output.folder}");
```

Is there a way to accomplish this within the route itself, instead of having the callee invoke the route multiple times by passing in the url of the endpoint each time?

Comment: I don't understand the flow of your code example. Who calls `direct:report`? And what dependency has this call to the multiple report endpoints? Does every report call need to query all three report endpoints? Are they different? And what does that mean to the output file? Do you want to write three different output files or just one?

Comment: @burki basically my `main()` function calls that direct endpoint. For now I just have 3 endpoints that I need to gather responses from. I configure those endpoints in a .properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're looking for [Recipient List](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/recipientList-eip.html). You have to use [custom aggregation strategy](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/recipientList-eip.html#_using_custom_aggregationstrategy) if you need to process all the responses.